# Unzipping Large File and Saving to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download a very large zip file, unzip and pipe the files to google cloud and then get each file from the bucket and download it to mongodb so there is no memory over load. I think I am doing everything right but I am still getting this error

<--- Last few GCs --->

[8143:0x150040000]   100257 ms: Scavenge 6856.9 (7026.4) -> 6850.6 (7030.9) MB, 22.5 / 0.4 ms  (average mu = 0.138, current mu = 0.113) allocation failure;
[8143:0x150040000]   100331 ms: Scavenge 6861.2 (7030.9) -> 6855.3 (7036.2) MB, 22.5 / 0.4 ms  (average mu = 0.138, current mu = 0.113) allocation failure;
[8143:0x150040000]   100522 ms: Scavenge 6865.2 (7036.2) -> 6859.7 (7041.2) MB, 17.8 / 0.2 ms  (average mu = 0.138, current mu = 0.113) external memory pressure;

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Here is the code I have so far

```
import axios from 'axios'
import AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
import { Storage } from '@google-cloud/storage'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { Readable } from 'stream'

const storage = new Storage()
const bucketName = process.env.BUCKET_NAME

// Fetch company filings data
async function fetchCompanyFilingsData() {
    const response = await axios.get(
        'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/bulkdata/submissions.zip',
        { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }
    )
    if (!response.data) {
        throw new Error('No data received from URL.')
    }
    return response.data
}

// Unzip and upload data to Google Cloud Storage
async function unzipAndUploadData(buffer: Buffer) {
    const zip = new AdmZip(buffer)
    const files = zip.getEntries().filter((file) => /\.json$/i.test(file.name))

    if (!files.length) {
        throw new Error('No JSON files found in ZIP archive.')
    }

    for (const file of files) {
        const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName)
        const blob = bucket.file(file.name)

        const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream()

        blobStream.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err)
        })

        blobStream.on('finish', () => {
            console.log(`Uploaded ${file.name} to Google Cloud Storage`)
            blobStream.end() // Close the writable stream
        })

        // Convert content (which is a Buffer) to a Stream
        const readableStream = new Readable()
        readableStream.push(file.getData())
        readableStream.push(null)

        // Pipe the stream to blobStream
        readableStream.pipe(blobStream)
    }
}

// Parse JSON files and save data to MongoDB
async function saveDataToMongoDB(db) {
    const filingsCollection = mongoose.connection.db.collection('edgar-filings')
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName)
    const [files] = await bucket.getFiles()

    for (const file of files) {
        if (file.name.endsWith('.json')) {
            const content = file.createReadStream() // Read the file as a readable stream

            let data = ''
            content.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk.toString()
            })

            content.on('end', async () => {
                const jsonData = JSON.parse(data)

                const existingFiling = await filingsCollection.findOne({ cik: jsonData.cik })
                if (!existingFiling) {
                    const result = await filingsCollection.insertOne(jsonData)
                    console.log('Inserted filing:', result)
                } else {
                    console.log('Filing already exists:', jsonData)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

export async function processCompanyFilingsData(db): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const buffer = await fetchCompanyFilingsData()
        await unzipAndUploadData(buffer)

        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI) // Replace with your MongoDB connection string
        await saveDataToMongoDB(db)
        await mongoose.disconnect()

        console.log('Data saved to MongoDB')
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: The catalog for a zip file is at the archive file end. That means most libraries will read the entire zip file into memory. Your errors tell you that you have run out of memory.